# Much vs very usage

Tags: adverbs

> 1. He is **much** interested in the project
> 2. He is **very** interested in the project.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: _Much_ means _a large quantity. Very_ means _to a great degree_. (1) would have to be _He shows/feels much interest in the project_.

Comment: The main difference is that [we used to use ***much***, but now we use ***very***...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He%20is%20much%20interested%2CHe%20is%20very%20interested&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20much%20interested%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20very%20interested%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20much%20interested%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20very%20interested%3B%2Cc0)